# HTML Table containing headers, table headers, body tag, and table data tag

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to make a 2x2 table so that the layout is "Mission Statement" and "Picture UMES" on one row then "2017" and the unordered list on the second row but can't seem to figure it out, it all displays as a list.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      background-color: gray;
      color: black;
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: gray;
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    table {
      background-color: white
    }
    
    th {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: smaller
    }
    
    td {
      background-color: gray;
      font-size: smaller
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      color: black;
      background-color: white
    }
    
    address {
      font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
      font-size: larger
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>University of Maryland Eastern Shore </h1>
  <table>
    <tr width="100%">
      <h2> UMES Mission Statement </h2>
      <th> Picture UMES </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <body> 2017 </body>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li> Picture of <a href="hawk_mascot.jpg"> our mascot </a> </li>
          <li> Picture of <a href="UMES_Campus.jpg"> our campus </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question please. See [mcve]

Comment: just realized i didn't add that sorry, new to posting here

Comment: Your HTML is invalid in multiple places. Try running it through a validator first. Ex: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: Matthew, that is the goal in terms of positioning but the "MissionStatement" and "2017" are supposed to be with white backgrounds, i had tried it that way before but it messed with the backgrounds

Comment: Raj has the answer... where you have gone wrong is that you should only use `th` and `td` as the direct children of `tr`

Comment: It does make a 2x2 table but the styling is important, I'm required to use an h2 tag and body tag, for the items I've applied them to, and contain all 4 aspects into one table

Comment: @EndlessClavicle your html will alway be broken and invalid then. You can only have one `body` tag per document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body. You can use `h2` but in a table in must be in a `th` or `td` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will reach your requirement

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Mission Statement</th>
        <th>Picture UMES</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2017</td>
        <td>
        <ul>
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While you are correct, you should explain where the OP went wrong and what your code does to fix it.

Comment: my answer says that you can reach your requirement if you follow this format

Comment: It does, but you should explain why it works when compared to what the asker has posted.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it up... colspan="2" what you looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    h1 {
      background-color: gray;
      color: black;
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: gray;
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: Verdana
    }
    
    table {
      background-color: white
    }
    
    th {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-size: smaller
    }
    
    td {
      background-color: gray;
      font-size: smaller
    }
    
    body {
      font-family: Arial;
      color: black;
      background-color: white
    }
    
    address {
      font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
      font-size: larger
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>University of Maryland Eastern Shore </h1>
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th><h2> UMES Mission Statement </h2></th>
      <th> Picture UMES </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <body> 2017 </body>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <ul>
          <li> Picture of <a href="hawk_mascot.jpg"> our mascot </a> </li>
          <li> Picture of <a href="UMES_Campus.jpg"> our campus </a> </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```